# How do the kleene plus operators apply here?

Tags: regex, regular-language, kleene-star

(cd<sup>+</sup>)<sup>+</sup>?

I have cd<sup>+</sup> to {cd, cdd, cddd, ...} but I do not understand how to apply the + from the parenthesis.

I saw that if it is like (d*)* then it is same as d* but here its not just d* in it but c without * or <sup>+</sup> and that is confusing me.

Comment: Did you [try it](https://regex101.com/r/8tuTIn/1)?

Comment: The superscript `+` is not the same as `+`.

Comment: Are you saying this is your regex `(cd⁺)⁺?` or is it this one `(cd⁺)+?` any you've made a typo. Both are valid regex. In these cases `⁺` is not a quantifier it's just a literal. `+` on the otherhand is a quantifier.

Comment: The competing visual signs are in fact `00207A    ⁺    SUPERSCRIPT PLUS SIGN` and 
`00002B    +    PLUS SIGN`